# How can I use OpenCV DescriptorMatcher on two arrays of points?

Tags: python, opencv

Is it possible to use [OpenCV DescriptorMatcher](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d39/classcv_1_1DescriptorMatcher.html) to match two arrays of points instead of two Descriptors generated by feature extraction functions?

I'd like to use OpenCV for point set registration, and I've obtained the two points sets without using feature extraction functions.

Comment: This seems kind of difficult, since the `cv2.DescriptorMatcher` is like the documentation says an abstract class which is inherited by the various Matcher classes. You might also be not successful to mimic an arrays an additional Matcher class since your mimic is not defined as Matcher in the enum of `cv2.DescriptorMatcher`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get descriptors for points from an image without the feature extractors.   There is a DescriptorExtractor class for this. Then you can use the appropriate matcher to find the corresondences.

If your points have only position information select a descriptor algorithm that works without angle and octave. E.g. BRIEF

Answer (score 0):

It turned out you can use array of points (2D arrays) for input to the matcher:

```
method = cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_L1
matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(method)
matches = matcher.match(src.astype(np.float32), dst.astype(np.float32), None)
```

src and dst are just 2D arrays of points to match